# How to run time-consuming task in parallel?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, rabbitmq

In order to enhance my application I plan to move a time-consuming task to run asynchronously and do some offline processing. The first idea that came to mind is using `hadoop` with a daemon thread. Unfortunately, the component we depend upon only runs on windows. Therefore, I have turned my attention toward queue technology. I find `rabbitmq` is a potential solution for us. But we don't have experience with this. We have some questions:

1. How would one go about monitoring the worker thread?
2. How to improve performance through creating more exchange?
3. How to load balance based on the worker machine idling resource?
4. How to do failover?

Do you think parallel computing with `rabbitmq` is good idea? If you have taste rabbitmq with parallel computing. Can you give me some suggestions or ideas?
Your answers and comments are appreciated.

**Note**:
Our task didn't cross worker machine (different to map/reduce). That is said, one task dispatch to only one worker machine.

Comment: Is there any actual relation to the [.net] and [task-parallel-library] tags?

Comment: You might consider creating a Windows Service on the worker machines, these services could watch folders for files, which could instruct the services to do work; the services could create files with the results of their work. You could also use MSMQ or the Registry to communicate.